# Passing a variable to the end of the command

Tags: powershell

I need to get all Exchange user mailboxes (cloud) whose TotalDeletedItemSize is greater than 10 GB.
This script works great:

> Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited |  Get-MailboxStatistics | select
>   DisplayName,TotalDeletedItemSize | Where {(($_.TotalDeletedItemSize
>   -split " ")[0]) -gt 10}

But I also need the output to contain the ALIAS.
If I pass the ALIAS using a select after the get-mailbox then the Get-MailboxStatistics throws an error.

Comment: either break your pipeline into independent steps - so that you can save the output of the 1st step - OR look into something like the `-PipelineVariable`. for more info, look at `Get-Help about_CommonParameters`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is with a foreach loop:

```
Foreach ($mb in (Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited)) {

   Get-MailboxStatistics $mb.GUID | select DisplayName,TotalDeletedItemSize,@{n="Alias";e={$mb.alias}} | Where {(($_.TotalDeletedItemSize -split " ")[0]) -gt 10}
}
```